# WooCommerce order status doesn't change on save_post_ action

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

I'm developing a WooCommerce plugin which I save extra metadata on `save_post_shop_order` action hook.
Now I want to add a logic which changes order status to 'pending' based on some conditions.
I figured out that no matter which status, the order status doesn't change in `save_post_shop_order` action hook.

```
function save_order_data(int $post_id)
{
$nonce_name = isset($_POST['save_invoice_nonce']) ? $_POST['save_invoice_nonce'] : '';
$nonce_action = 'save_invoice';

if (!wp_verify_nonce($nonce_name, $nonce_action)) {
    return;
}
if (!current_user_can('edit_shop_orders', $post_id)) {
    return;
}

if (wp_is_post_autosave($post_id)) {
    return;
}

if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
    return;
}

$order = wc_get_order($post_id);
$order->update_status('pending'); // This command works but it seems order status is being overwritten maybe by WooCommerce to previous status


}

add_action('save_post_shop_order', 'save_order_data', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally had to use Transients to remember doing status change in next page load and then change order status on `woocommerce_after_register_post_type` hook.

Comment: Many thanks! Great idea for using transients, saved me a lot of time